# Android Things with Crashlytics error

Tags: crashlytics, android-things

I use Android Things Developer Preview 7.
Without Crashlytics my app works properly.
When I install fabric.Crashylitics on the code:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

I receive the following error:

```
     Caused by: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
    install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:233)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:207)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:440)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:384)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:342)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:313)
        at androidthings.project.alarm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6991)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
```

Does Crashlytics support Android Things?

Comment: Looks like you are missing the Crashlytics dependency, did you install / import it properly?

Comment: of course. I use fabric for my main android (not things) project. And it works perfectly.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. We haven't tested against the Dev Preview or Android things so it's entirely possible that it doesn't work.